# In which directory should I extract and install gtk+, glib, gdk-pixbuf, pango in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, gtk, glib

I am trying to install the latest version of GTK+ and I have downloaded all the packages listed here:

> http://www.gtk.org/download-linux.html

In which directory should I extract each of the tar files and then install?

Note: the installation instructions (where there is an INSTALL file) are the standard `./configure`, `make` and `make install`. It therefore seems to me that it's important where I extract each of the files.

Answer (score 1):

You should extract them into and build them in a normal user's home directory. You should install them into `/usr/local` via `sudo`.

Comment: So you are saying I should just extract them into /home/administrator, but then you are just suppose to type "make install". Will this put it in the right directory?

Comment: First you extract them. The you read the `INSTALL` file that comes along with each.

Comment: Yes I've read the INSTALL file. So just following the instructions will put them in the right directory? And what would happen if I don't put them in the home directory?

Comment: Well, they don't *need* to be in the home directory per se, but really, as long as you can build them as a normal user that's fine.

Comment: Would /usr/src be another option?

Comment: If the normal user has write access to each extracted directory under there, sure.

Comment: After I've extracted the files there, why would it be necessary to have write access?

Comment: If I've extracted the files to /usr/src, I'm able to write using sudo & then each user will just run the program. So it is still necessary for each user to have write access?

Comment: Software should not be built as root, so that any rogue processes don't end up causing damage to the system. Yes, it is still possible to cause damage during `sudo make install`, but it is likely that any traps existing in tampered software would just be done triggered during the build for simplicity, which would catch less-experienced people.

Comment: Ok thanks. So it seems resolved we can extract the files in any directory as long as we can build there but it's best not do in directories requiring us to build as root. I've also found I needed to do the following:
[1] After installing glib, run ldconfig (I had an old version of glib installed).
[2] After installing pango, set PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/gtk/lib/pkgconfig:<directory where you extracted the pango package>/pango-1.28.4 i.e. add the directory containing pango.pc to PKG_CONFIG_PATH"

Comment: `make install` should put the .pc files in the appropriate place already.

Comment: Ok I figured out the problem. I had followed the instructions here http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.0/gtk-building.html to set the environment variables to install in gtk3 in /opt/gtk (e.g. you can see the /opt/grk/lib/pkgconfig in PKG_CONFIG_PATH above) but I wasn't installing in /opt/gtk, I was just running ./config without the prefix variable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes so just following the instructions in the INSTALL file: `./configure`, `make`, `make install`; works fine. It gets installed by default into `/usr/local/share`

I prefer to extract it to the home folder just in case the tar is needed again in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The classic method to use when building from source is:

1. Extract the package to a working directory (/tmp is an easy default choice)

   ```
   tar -xzf package-src.tgz -C /tmp/
   ```
2. Change to the extracted directory:

   ```
   cd /tmp/package-src
   ```
3. Configure the makefile as needed for your platform/environment (setting the base dir to /usr/local as well is a good idea):

   ```
   ./configure
   ```
4. Compile the app, run the makefile's tests and finally install the finalized files using chained commands:

   ```
   make && make test && sudo make install
   ```